# Plot tree like structure with images as nodes in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

I am plotting nodes with `treeplot(nodes)` and I want to replace the node symbols (by default circles) with images.

The treeplot function in Matlab works with the following graph notation:

```
nodes = [0,1,1,2,2]
```

where the position of elements is the node number, the values represent the parent node. example node 1 is the root so value 0. node 2 and 3 are the children of node 1 similarly it goes on.

When passing this vector to one of the funtion in matlab

```
treeplot(nodes)
```

we get a tree like structure:

[image: output of treeplot(nodes) with nodes = [0,1,1,2,2]]

In this plot I want images instead of node symbols (circles). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`[x,y] = treelayout(nodes)`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/treelayout.html) to get the `x`- and `y`-coordinates of your nodes in `treeplot(nodes)`. Then use `hold on` and `image` to draw into your plot.

The following example uses a MATLAB sample image and resizes the images to 5% of the plot. Images are centered on the nodes (with the `0.5*size multiplication` added to the coordinates) and labels are added (using `text`).

```
img = imread('peppers.png');    % MATLAB demo image
sizeX = 0.05; sizeY = 0.05;     % Define image size in plot
[x,y] = treelayout(nodes);      % get x,y of nodes in plot

nodes = [0,1,1,2,2];
treeplot(nodes);                        
hold on;                        % add to your treeplot

for i=1:length(x)               % for all nodes do:

    % draw image centered at node
    image([x(i)-0.5*sizeX x(i)+0.5*sizeX], ...
            [y(i)+0.5*sizeY y(i)-0.5*sizeY],img);

    % optional: label
    text(x(i),y(i),num2str(i),'Color','white');

end
```

[image: Resulting image of code: Treeplot with images and labels]